# How can I determine the capacitance required for an oscillator (NOT A CRYSTAL!)?

Tags: oscillator, clock, capacitance

In a typical clocking circuit configuration, where a crystal is tied at the input to an amplifier such as is shown below:

[image: Clock Circuit Configuration]

The capacitance required for \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ would be based on the load capacitance equation (sorry, not sure how to format equations on SE):

$$C_L = \frac{C_{1}\times C_{2}}{C_{1}+C_{2}}+C_S$$

However, what happens when you use an oscillator... such as the [ACH-25.000MHZ-EK](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/3/ach-46940.pdf)?

There is nothing in the application notes about needing a capacitor, so do I actually need one? (and for *oscillators* in general?) I am thinking that because this is still an oscillating circuit, similar to the crystal (clock configuration circuit)... That I will still need some sort of capacitor to keep the oscillator stable. Or am I wrong, and do I not need to attach any capacitor(s) to either the output or GND pins?

Comment: You don't need a capacitor. This oscillator circuit is providing a clock signal out of the box (well, just power it...)

Comment: Additionally, having trouble viewing pictures I've pasted into my question... Not sure if others are having difficulties.

Comment: Ok @EugeneSh. but won't the rest of the circuit's capacitance, somehow have to factor into how the oscillator output should be stabilized?

Comment: @Snoopy: which CPU? datasheet!

Comment: @Curd Not talking about a CPU here, but if you must know... in my application I specifically use an AD9833 that takes a 25MHz signal from the ACH chip (datasheet provided in question). I am more discussing general design principles in this question, and not directly having a problem related to my application.

Comment: @Snoopy: but the AD9833 has only ONE clock input (no oscillator on chip, just a clock input); see also Evaluation Board Schematic in datasheet. So you question doesn't make sense.

Comment: On StackExchange you have [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations.

Comment: @Arsenal Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, you need no capacitor.
Just connect the external (crystal or whatever) oscillator output to the oscillator **input** of the CPU (OSC1 or OSC2; or maybe called XTAL1 or XTAL2) and leave the other terminal unconnected. Only one of them is input and you need to find out which one of them by looking into the datasheet. I'm sure the datasheet tells you how to connect the external clock.

Here is an example from the ATmega32 datasheet:

[image]

Comment: The question specifically states that I am not talking about a crystal.

Comment: I'm also NOT talking about a crystal! Where do you read that I'm talking about a crystal?!?

Comment: Yes, I re-read your answer. You are right.

Comment: Easy, more curt than curd here :-)